# Browser Language Redirection For Multi Language Stores In Magento 2

Tags: magento2, multistore, redirect, htaccess

Anybody knows how to use the following piece of code? I want detect visitors browser language and than redirect for the right multi language store. Want to use subfolders (www.domain.com/en/), not multi (www.en.domain.com) domains.

```
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'website2';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

Comment: did u get any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To detect browser language check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770513/detect-browser-language-in-php.

Depending on the found valid language you can set your store view code as PARAM_RUN_CODE and "store" as PARAM_RUN_TYPE.

To edit the used base URL, check this out: [Link store view to different Url in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/230268/link-store-view-to-different-url-in-magento-2)