# Link store view to different Url in magento 2

Tags: magento2, multistore

I created a new store view with code 'fr'. I have changed the base Url of that store view to 'http://127.0.0.1/magento/fr/'. I created the new folder with name 'fr' and copied .htaccess file and index.php inside it. Now I changed index.php like below:

```
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'fr';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'store';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

Now when I am hitting 'http://127.0.0.1/magento/fr/' it's showing the default store view instead of store view with code 'fr'. Can anyone tell what's wrong with the procedure ? Thanks!

Comment: Happy coding :) @mighty_hk. You can upvote on this answer so other user can use this answer for their solution.

Comment: Aur kitni reputation chahiye bhai ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this step to add store code in url :

- In the Admin, click **Stores > Settings > Configuration > General >
  Web**.
- From the Store View list at the top of the page, click Default Config
  as the following figure shows.
- In the right pane, expand Url Options.
- Clear the Use system value checkbox next to Add Store Code to Urls.
- From the Add Store Code to Urls list, click Yes as the following figure shows.
- Click Save Config.
- Flush the Magento cache. (System > Cache Management).